# How to find code called by suspend_ops->enter(state);

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, power-management

I am trying to understand the linux kernel power management at a low level and have finally got stuck since my C is not very strong. I am able to follow the code down to where it calls `suspend_ops->enter(state);` in the `suspend_enter(suspend_state_t state, bool *wakeup)` method (`kernel/power/suspend.c`) however I have not been able to follow the code any further.

It is my understanding that `suspend_ops->enter(state)` is invoking the "enter" method in some drivers that registered themselves with suspend_ops but I am not sure how to find them or the method that is being called. Can someone please tell me how to follow the `suspend_ops->enter(state)` call?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Where is the handoff from Android to kernel...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501349/where-is-the-handoff-from-andoid-to-kernel-for-power-state-transitions)

Comment: Please specify the platform you are interested in.  Do you have a cellphone or tablet name?  Johnathon's list is missing a few, because his source is pretty old.  There are more in the current kernel.  It helps to know your kernel version too.  The calls are through [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).  Running `dmesg | grep -i power` might help.

Comment: Not a duplicate of my other question as I intended this one to apply to the linux kernel in general and not a specific architecture.

Thanks for tip on function pointers.

Comment: There is no difference for the **ARM** Linux suspend/resume and the non-ARM suspend/resume.  They just call different function pointers for each platform.  By your logic, you could ask the same question for every occurrence of `suspend_set_ops()`.  It is not the same identical question, but it is splitting hairs to say it is significantly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the top of `kernel/power/suspend.c` note the line:

```
static struct platform_suspend_ops *suspend_ops;
```

This means that `suspend_ops` is a global variable that is private to this file. This means that in order to be of any use, there will have to be an assignment somewhere in `suspend.c`. So let's look for the assignment. Searching through `suspend.c` for `suspend_ops` we see only one assignment, in the subroutine `suspend_set_ops`. Searching for `suspend_set_ops` in `suspend.c` we see that there are no calls to it. So, the calls must be somewhere else!

We search the entire kernel for `suspend_set_ops`:

```
yba@tavas:~/linux-2.6/linux-2.6.31$ find . -type f | xargs grep suspend_set_ops
./kernel/power/suspend.c: * suspend_set_ops - Set the global suspend method table.
./kernel/power/suspend.c:void suspend_set_ops(struct platform_suspend_ops *ops)
./arch/mips/alchemy/devboards/pm.c: suspend_set_ops(&db1x_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-sa1100/pm.c:    suspend_set_ops(&sa11x0_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/plat-s3c/pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(&s3c_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm24xx.c: suspend_set_ops(&omap_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c: suspend_set_ops(&omap_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-pxa/pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(&pxa_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-pxa/sharpsl_pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(&sharpsl_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-pxa/sharpsl_pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(NULL);
./arch/arm/mach-at91/pm.c:  suspend_set_ops(&at91_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-omap1/pm.c: suspend_set_ops(&omap_pm_ops);
./arch/arm/mach-pnx4008/pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(&pnx4008_pm_ops);
./arch/sh/kernel/cpu/shmobile/pm.c: suspend_set_ops(&sh_pm_ops);
./arch/sh/boards/mach-hp6xx/pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(&hp6x0_pm_ops);
./arch/powerpc/platforms/83xx/suspend.c:    suspend_set_ops(&mpc83xx_suspend_ops);
./arch/powerpc/platforms/52xx/mpc52xx_pm.c: suspend_set_ops(&mpc52xx_pm_ops);
./arch/powerpc/platforms/52xx/lite5200_pm.c:    suspend_set_ops(&lite5200_pm_ops);
./arch/avr32/mach-at32ap/pm.c:  suspend_set_ops(&avr32_pm_ops);
./arch/blackfin/mach-common/pm.c:   suspend_set_ops(&bfin_pm_ops);
./include/linux/suspend.h: * suspend_set_ops - set platform dependent suspend operations
./include/linux/suspend.h:extern void suspend_set_ops(struct platform_suspend_ops *ops);
./include/linux/suspend.h:static inline void suspend_set_ops(struct platform_suspend_ops *ops) {}
./drivers/macintosh/via-pmu.c:  suspend_set_ops(&pmu_pm_ops);
./drivers/acpi/sleep.c: suspend_set_ops(old_suspend_ordering ?
```

What we see is that almost all of the calls to `suspend_set_ops` are in the architecture-specific directories, except for the two drivers at the end of the output: `macintosh/via-pmu.c` and `acpi/sleep.c`. So the next step is to look at the architecture-specific code for some platform. We'll use `./arch/powerpc/platforms/83xx/suspend.c` as an example. You should do this yourself for whatever platform you are using. If it is x86, then you probably need to look in `./drivers/acpi/sleep.c`.

Searching for `suspend_set_ops` in that file we see that it is called once, in the subroutine `pmc_probe` which is static. So we look for calls to `pmc_probe` in the same file until we find one that is not static. We find a static declaration of a structure of type `` `of_platform_driver `` called `pmc_driver`that assigns`pmc_probe`to element`probe``.

Since the `pmc_driver` structure is static, we look for references to it in the same file, and fine one, in the static function `pmc_init`. We look for calls to `pmc_init` and find one, as a parameter to the `module_init` call.

We search for `module_init` from the top of the kernel tree, limiting our search slightly:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -w "module_init.*)[^;]" |more
```

Of the results we get, the most promissing is:

```
./include/linux/init.h:#define module_init(initfn)                  \
```

Looking in `./include/linux/init.h` we see that `module_init` is a call to `__initcall` if MODULE is not defined or else

```
#define module_init(initfn)                                     \
    static inline initcall_t __inittest(void)               \
    { return initfn; }                                      \
    int init_module(void) __attribute__((alias(#initfn)));
```

At this point we are really on another subject - how drivers and modules are registered. HTH.

Comment: +1 `cd arch/arm` followed by `git grep suspend_set_ops` and get  similar.  I guess his platform is **arm**.  Certainly, I don't know of Android PowerPC implementations.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, got a bit busy. I did what you suggested at first but didn't think of looking in the acpi driver files (it was a long week) so thanks for helping me out.